# How do I add a dependency to docker container?

Tags: docker, boost

I want to run a C++ program that uses `boost asio` in a docker container. But my container doesn't seem to know anything about boost.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-gcc
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ && /usr/bin/g++ -o server main.cpp connection_manager.cpp connection.cpp 
mime_types.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp -lboost_system - 
lboost_thread -lpthread -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost

CMD ["./server"]
```

I write command `$docker build` and get:

[image]

Why so?

Comment: Q: Why are you *COMPILING* your C++ program in Docker???  Why don't you build it beforehand, and copy the C++ *EXECUTABLE* (along with any dependent runtime libraries) into your Docker load?

Comment: @FoggyDay because my job is to build and compile in a container

Comment: `docker build` usually writes out text output, not a PNG file.  Can you edit the question to replace the image with the actual error you're getting?  Do you think your image contains the Boost libraries?

Answer (score 1):

What is your `frolvlad/alpine-gcc` base image? I assume it's just gcc loaded into alpine...

You can achieve the same effect with:

```
FROM alpine:3.10 AS build

# Load build packages
RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
  build-base \
  boost boost-dev
```

Followed by your `RUN` command etc.

There is a working example two stage Dockerfile to build an HTTP server using boost asio here: https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: I rewrote my RUN command to `RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
  build-base \
  boost boost-dev && /usr/bin/g++ -o server main.cpp connection_manager.cpp connection.cpp mime_types.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp -lboost_system - lboost_thread -lpthread -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost` **and get an error**: `g++: error: lboost_thread: No such file or directory`

Comment: Look at the example in the link. I prefer to use `cmake` instead of a very long g++ command, which is prone to errors.